# Kotlin 'unsafe call on nullable receiver' compile error after null check

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

This is the screenshot of the error: [image: Error Screenshot]

I'm using Intellij v14.0.1 + Kotlin plugin v0.9.206. My understanding is that after the null check, the compiler shouldn't show me the error. Am I wrong?

Comment: Your question should contain the declaration for the `target` member of the class represented by `person`.  The declaration changes the answer.  Although the error message is different for when you have a custom getter on a property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target` property is `var`, that's why it's not guarantee that on the third line this property couldn't be null (e.g. another thread could set it to `null`)

Comment: Also to note, that if the property is `val` but has custom `get()` getter then it also cannot be used with a smart cast caused by the `if` check for `null`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a property can be a method call and then nothing can be guaranteed. Use a local `val`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Both of answers are great and it makes more sense to me now. However, I'm not sure which answer is 'more correct' so I chose the earlier one. Sorry

Comment: @user3097196 I'm perfectly fine with it. Hint: You can upvote the other one. Just kidding (and I guess it was you who did).

Comment: This is not always true.  A property without a custom getter can still be smart cast by an `if` check for `null`